# `+=` leads to `none` with class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, operator-overloading

I just want to use the `__add__` modifier, to use '+=' to easily add to elements of a classinstance:

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lItems = []

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.lItems.append(other)


problem = Problem()
problem += 'text'
print(problem)
```

The resulting problem will equal `None`after the `+=`. Why? And how can I prevent that from happening?

P.S.: I have also tried implementing `__iadd__` with no effect...

Comment: `__add__` needs to return a value.

Comment: Even     `def __add__(self, other): return self.lItems.append(other)` does not work...

Comment: No, because `append` itself returns None.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Making `__add__` return `self` does the trick:

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lItems = []

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.lItems.append(other)
        return self


problem = Problem()
problem += 'text'
print(problem)
print(problem.lItems)
```

outputs :

```
<__main__.Problem object at 0x04BBDCD0>
['text']
```

EDIT:
You should consider the use of [`__iadd__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__iadd__) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You need to return the new state of the instance from `__add__`:

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lItems = []

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.lItems.append(other)
        return self
```

However, now you have a problem when using + on its own:

```
a = Problem()

b = a + 5

print (a)
print (b)
```

results in:

```
<__main__.Problem instance at 0x0022BE40>
<__main__.Problem instance at 0x0022BE40>
```

`a` and `b` are the same instance! We would expect `b` to be different from `a`, with an extra object in its lItems.

This is why you want to use the `__iadd__` method. It only works on `+=`:

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lItems = []

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.lItems.append(other)
        return self
```

... and using + results in an error, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

After your `append` operation, you need to `return` the object.

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lItems = []

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.lItems.append(other)
        return self
```

Example

```
>>> problem = Problem()
>>> problem += 'text'
>>> problem.lItems
['text']
>>> problem += 'foobar'
>>> problem.lItems
['text', 'foobar']
```